# Room database: how to retrieve column names into list of strings?

Tags: android-room

I have a Room table named "addresses" with 15 columns. I retrieve one row and want to get values into List< String >, not List< Addresses >. Is that possible?

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE myid= :id")
List<String> getAddressAsList(int id);
```

Moreover, is it possible to retrieve database table column names together with values into list of map <"column name","value"> like this?

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE myid= :id")
List<Map<String, String> getAddressAsList(int id);
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Have you got the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SupportSQLiteDatabase but not a Dao.

Say you have, in an activity,

```
db = yourRoomDatabase.getInstance(this);
```

- i.e. you'd typically then use something like `yourDao = db.getYourDao();` and then
  `myAddressList = dao.getAddressList();`

You can then do:-

```
SupportSQLiteDatabase sdb = db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
Cursor csr = sdb.query("SELECT * FROM address WHERE myid=?",new String[]{String.value(id)}
```

Then to get the list of column names in the Cursor you can use:-

```
    val columnNames = csr.columnNames
```

To get the Map of columnnames and values you could use :-

```
    val columnsAndValues: MutableMap<String,String> = mutableMapOf()
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        for (i: Int in 0..csr.columnCount) {
            columnsAndValues.put(csr.columnNames.get(i),csr.getString(i))
        }
    }
    csr.close()
```

Comment: Why `getWritableDatabase`? We can do `getReadableDatabase` for safety reasons.

Comment: No. The OP asked how to get column names. You can get `columnNames` from `ReadableDatabase` too.

Comment: However, it is still better to use `getReadableDatabase` than `getWritableDatabase` in the code to have cases like full disk problems covered for the question that OP stated to retrieve just column names. Although the for the majority of usage is the same object, but it is better to use more adequate API.